# Bash grep stopping at first match

Tags: bash

```
user9@totl.example.com>, size=35020827, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<2m96JLQblfm/fh.01u3YnFYK0bc3pmOExg2vA.totl.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=lemur.totl.example.com
user11@shoe-bags.example.com>, size=18071179, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<BhaYKoWuhDhrUQcT5.+tF6eKTCu0459KjSflNxLg.shoe-bags.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=dog.shoe-bags.example.com
user23@stellar-patrol.example.com>, size=27057917, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<VaD1xW8SduAYImck.Mbx1MBcKTjBPlQpcaDhJRA.stellar-patrol.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=feinstein.stellar-patrol.example.com
user6@planet-express.example.com>, size=15212380, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<4wN8i90XT.BIdywWoKxNjeEM1q.planet-express.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=fry.planet-express.example.com
user19@blackmesa.example.com>, size=44656174, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<1froj29vndf7h0.Qzoi+1hDEQOVp1frnQvWO.blackmesa.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=barney.blackmesa.example.com
user2@stellar-patrol.example.com>, size=4556372, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<jnugzy+Z.L82rx1mhoSXi0RmK/yNP.stellar-patrol.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=feinstein.stellar-patrol.example.com
user7@macrohard.example.com>, size=35391498, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<fXr7+HM1U7ZpbJqxf.iJs6q9r.macrohard.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=corporate-mail-01.macrohard.example.com
user7@lawanda.example.com>, size=46296174, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<UJHE3Y4uEn.JBT3RESrNYL+fH5dFTGt5A.lawanda.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=achilles.lawanda.example.com
user14@feddit.example.com>, size=12197030, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<gpq6lYSHHC67d.ZjyKUitfcPwOlA/OEc++.feddit.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=kittin.feddit.example.com
```

I wish to extract just the email address part of each line, for example user9@tot1.example.com

I am currently using this technique:

```
cat file | grep -o 'user.*?com'
```

however since '.com' is at the end of the line occasionly i somehow still get the whole line returned.

my example output should look something like:

```
user9@totl.example.com
user11@shoe-bags.example.com
user23@stellar-patrol.example.com
... etc
```

How would this be possible? many thanks for help

Comment: Useless Use Of Cat spotted!

Comment: `grep` doesn't change the lines. It just shows you the lines that contain the regex you provided. You want to use `sed`. See `man grep` and `man sed`. Also, are those original lines correct? I would expect the email string to start with `<` if it ends with `>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
grep -o 'user[^[:space:]]\+\.com' file
```

and observe I don't need a `cat` here.

This uses the character class `[:space:]`. What I'm saying is that I want everything that starts with `user`, that ends with `.com` and that contains only non-space characters (and at least one) in between (`[^[:space:]]\+`).

---

Regarding your solution: you need the `-P` switch for `grep` to use Perl's regexp, so that `.*?` is interprated as *match anything, non-greedily*:

```
grep -Po 'user.*?com' file
```

would work.

Now I hope you don't have any guests with email `user42@coolcompagny.com` or similar, otherwise this one will fail here, as you'd obtain just `user42@coolcom` `:(`

Parsing email addresses with a regex is not a simple task at all.

Comment: This works great, could you give me a quick run down on how this code works? I'm fairly new to regex

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk to get parts of that line. In your case, it would be something like:

```
cat file | grep -o 'user.*?com' | awk -F',' '{print $1}'
```

For more functionality, you should check out the GNU Awk User Guide http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: You don't even need cat and grep. awk is enough. Notice there is `>` at the end of email address

Answer (score 0):

The .*? pattern only works if you give grep the -P option, which enables Perl-style regexps. Add that and it should work.